# HBase shell is starting but throwing error

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to run the HBase shell. The shell get starts but when I put any command it gives me this error:

```
 hbase:001:0> status

 ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ServerNotRunningYetException: Server is not running yet
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkServiceStarted(HMaster.java:2817)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.isMasterRunning(MasterRpcServices.java:1205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(Mas                                                                             terProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:334)

 For usage try 'help "status"'
```

This I got from my log file:

```
  [RS-EventLoopGroup-1-4] concurrent.DefaultPromise: An exception was thrown by org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.asyncfs.FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper$4.operationComplete()
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.asyncfs.ProtobufDecoder.<init>(ProtobufDecoder.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.asyncfs.FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.processWriteBlockResponse(FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.asyncfs.FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.access$100(FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.asyncfs.FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper$4.operationComplete(FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.java:425)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.asyncfs.FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.initialize(FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.asyncfs.FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.access$300(FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.asyncfs.FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper$5.operationComplete(FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.asyncfs.FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper$5.operationComplete(FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.java:472)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:605)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractEpollChannel.java:653)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:691)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:567)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:470)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

This is my hbase-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://hbase.cluster:9000/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/zookeeperData</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
</property>
```

This is my hbase-env.sh file, I have just this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

When I do jps, it shows me these:

```
731259 SecondaryNameNode
974862 QuorumPeerMain
730985 NameNode
995734 HMaster
1497628 Jps
689072 ResourceManager
976565 HRegionServer
```

Can somebody please help me. I am stuck on this for past 2 weeks. First it was giving me different errors like HMaster was not running and other zookeeper errors. I changed my xml file many times. Every time the error changes but the shell doesn't work when I try to run any command.
I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Please if someone can help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not related to hbase shell. The problem is that your HBase master cannot start, so the whole HBase cluster is not running.

Are you running one of the more recent versions of HBase? Like 2.4.x or so?

In this case, try to put the following entry into your hbase-site.xml (for the whole cluster):

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.wal.provider</name>
  <value>filesystem</value>
</property>
```

I experienced a similar issue while trying out the more recent releases of HBase, and specifying the WAL provider that way seems to have addressed the issue. If you keep running into other issues, it is a good idea to check the logs of the Master and Regionserver rather than trying to guess what's happening in hbase shell.

-Vadim

Comment: Thank you Vadim. It solved this error. But I am getting new error now when I try to create tables in hbase shell. I think I need to clear zookeeper data and start it again.

Comment: You can post the new errors in your question, let's have a look.